# List item is deleted from ListView, but not from the database

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview

I have a custom ListView adapter. In the ListView I set a delete button.

[image]

Now I want to delete the fixed list item by clicking on that list's button. I have been able to delete it from the ListView. But when I refresh my layout activity, the list is shown in the same place.

Maybe it wasn't deleted from the database. I created the database in my main activity. But I deleted the list item from ListView adapter activity.

This is my ListView adapter:

```
import static com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet.Constant.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet.Constant.SECOND_COLUMN;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
public ArrayList<HashMap> list;
Activity activity;


public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();


    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course_display_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_code);
        holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_title);
        ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_delete);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        delete.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        list.remove(position);
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();



                                    }
                                }
        );
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap map = list.get(position);
    holder.txtFirst.setText((CharSequence) map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    holder.txtSecond.setText((CharSequence) map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

In my AddCourseActivity (main activity) I used:

```
public class AddCourseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText editCourseCode,editCourseTitle;
Button btnAdd,btnEdit,btnSearch,btnShowAll;
ImageButton btnDelete;

SQLiteDatabase db;
ListView listview;
int i;

ArrayList<String> ar =null;
ArrayList<String> ar1 =null;
ArrayList<String> SampleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

private ArrayList<HashMap> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_course);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    editCourseCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.courseCode);
    editCourseTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.courseTitle);
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    btnShowAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show);
    btnEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);


    db = openOrCreateDatabase("CourseDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course(courseCode VARCHAR, courseTitle VARCHAR)");


    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnShowAll.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View view){
    if (view == btnAdd){
        String str = editCourseCode.getText().toString().trim();
        String str1 = editCourseTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        if(str.length()>0 && str1.length()>0){
            db.execSQL("insert into course values('" + str + "','" + str1 + "')");
            Snackbar.make(view, "Inserted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editCourseCode.setText("");
            editCourseTitle.setText("");
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Not Inserted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else if(view == btnShowAll){
        try {

            final ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            populateList();
            final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
            lview.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "No record found", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else if(view==btnEdit){
        if(editCourseCode.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 && editCourseTitle.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){
            Snackbar.make(view, "Not Updated", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (editCourseCode.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE course set courseTitle='"+editCourseTitle.getText()+"' WHERE " + " courseCode ='"+editCourseCode.getText()+"'");
            }
            else if (editCourseTitle.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE course set courseCode='"+editCourseCode.getText()+"' WHERE " + " courseTitle ='"+editCourseTitle.getText()+"'");
            }
            Snackbar.make(view, "Updated", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
private void populateList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ar = new ArrayList();
    ar1 = new ArrayList();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from course", null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    do {
        ar.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("courseCode")));
        ar1.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("courseTitle")));
    } while (c.moveToNext());


    list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    for ( i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {

        HashMap temp = new HashMap();
        temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, ar.get(i));
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, ar1.get(i));
        list.add(temp);
    }

}







@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_course, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_profile:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}




}
```

How can I delete the fixed list item from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to run a delete query in your database table as well when you are removing from the list. So the `onClickListener` should look like this.

```
ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_delete);
convertView.setTag(holder);
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Delete from database as well
        db.rawQuery("delete from course where courseCode = '" + list.get(position).get(FIRST_COLUMN) + "'", null);

        // Now delete from list and update your ListView
        list.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

**Update**

Based on the update of the question. I have modified your adapter and introduced some new variables in it. Please check the adapter and import the packages necessary in this adapter. Then modify the place from where you initiate the adapter.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<HashMap> list;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtFirst;
        TextView txtSecond;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.course_display_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_code);
            holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_title);
            ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t_delete);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            delete.setOnClickListener
                    (new View.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("CourseDB", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                             db.execSQL("DELETE from course where courseCode = '" + list.get(position).get(FIRST_COLUMN) + "'");
                             db.close();

                             list.remove(position);
                             notifyDataSetChanged();
                         }
                     }
                    );
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap map = list.get(position);
        holder.txtFirst.setText((CharSequence) map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        holder.txtSecond.setText((CharSequence) map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: db of db.rawQuery can't be solved. how can I get main activity's db in listview adapter activity??

Comment: The same way you open the database in your main activity. Just pass the context from the main activity when you are initializing your adapter.

Comment: Will it be..
    final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list, SQLiteDatabase.db);  ???

Comment: No. You are passing the context already I guess. Just use the context to open the database in your adapter. And then execute the query in your database. `ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);` - is fine.

Comment: Sir,please write the method for opening database. I tried in my way... but it was wrong.

Comment: You have called a database query in your `populateList` function. You need to open the database in the same way. Please share the initialization of your `db` variable in your `populateList` function, so that I can help.

Comment: Sir, can you give me your email address? I want to send you the documents than you can help me in proper way. I need your help so much. Because I want to learn it seriously. I tried my best what I could. Please Sir, help me.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work this way. We are all here to help each other. So this is really important to ask a clear question with enough details. Please update your question with the code for initializing the database and then comment here notifying that you have updated your question. Thanks.

Comment: Sir, I didn't get how to get the databse in listview adapter to delete the from button on list. Maybe I didn't get you in proper way. That was my question. Thank you Sir for trying to help me.

Comment: Please post your class in your question which contains the `populateList` function.

Comment: Sir, in this update solution, there was no error. But still the same problem. Its not deleting from database.

Comment: Please check if the script is executed correctly. And how did you understand that the entry is not deleted from your database? Please put logs where necessary to understand what is exactly happening here.

Comment: I understood the entity was not deleted because of after clicking view button all list again shown on the list like before deleting those.

Comment: '04-02 02:22:05.035 17592-17601/com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet/databases/CourseDB' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.'

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check if its working now.

Comment: Sir, again same problem.

Comment: `04-02 09:06:27.084 4874-4874/com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
04-02 09:06:27.129 4874-4883/com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 40
04-02 09:06:27.138 4874-4914/com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0x7f7d89f000
04-02 09:06:32.693 4874-4874/com.example.shubho.digitalattendancesheet D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0 `

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I have found the solution for that problem taking help from an expert. I have edited the code line, `db.execSQL("DELETE from course where courseCode = '" + list.get(position).get(FIRST_COLUMN) + "'");` and it worked.

Comment: Great to know that you could solve your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

in `OnClick` for the delete button, create a worker thread and execute a db query to delete the item. 
You would need to uniquely identify the item in the list, so basically you need some sort of id on your item (which I presume you already have)

You can use `AsyncTask`, `Handlers` or `Threads` to do this. Don't execute db queries on main thread otherwise your app would lag.

**On a side note.** Stop using `notifyDataSetChanged` and instead use `notifyItemRemoved`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Interface` inside adapter class

```
interface OnDeleteListener {
    onDeleteCourse(String code, int position)
}
```

Add this constructor to **Adapter** class

```
private OnDeleteListenre mListener;    

public ListViewAdapter(List<HashMap> items, OnDeleteListener listener) {
    mListener = listener
    ...
}
```

Add this method inside **Adapter** class

```
public void refresh(int position) {
    // remove the item from the list
    list.remove(position)
    // refresh listview
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Change `delete` button implementation like below

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // get the course code from the list according to position
                ...
                ...
                // pass this code and item position here
                mListener.onDelete(## PASS COURSE CODE HERE ##, position);
            }
        });
```

Let the `Activity` class `implement OnDeleteListener` and

```
 @Override
public void onDeleteCourse(String code, int postion) {
   // Delete the course from the database here
   ...
   ... 
   // notify the adapter 
   adapter.refresh(position)
}
```

Initialize the Adapter

```
adapter = ListViewAdapter(list, this)
```